# Why my result list is empty?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, join

Why my result list is empty?
What do I wrong? I have two rows in my tables, but result is empty always.

Table1:

[image: http://screencast.com/t/4Uyaq8FFFsh]

Table2:

[image: http://screencast.com/t/g08WGBmPVbu]

Parameter phone (I see in debug mode) same as in table.

```
List<IAppEntity> list = entityManager.createQuery(
                "SELECT a FROM IAppsFriends c" +
                        " JOIN c.apps a" +
                        " WHERE c.phone=:phone")
                .setParameter("phone", phone).getResultList();
```

IAppsFriends:

```
    @Entity
        @Table(name = "IAppsFriends")
        public class IAppsFriends {

            @GeneratedValue
            @Id
            private int id;

            @OneToMany(mappedBy = "packageName")
            private List<IAppEntity> apps;

            private String phone;

            public int getId() {
                return id;
            }

            public void setId(int id) {
                this.id = id;
            }

            public List<IAppEntity> getApps() {
                return apps;
            }

            public void setPackageName(List<IAppEntity> apps) {
                this.apps = apps;
            }

            public String getPhone() {
                return phone;
            }

            public void setPhone(String phone) {
                this.phone = phone;
            }

        }
```

IAppEntety:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "IApp")
public class IAppEntity {

    @Id
    private String packageName;

    public IAppsFriends getFriends() {
        return friends;
    }

    public void setFriends(IAppsFriends friends) {
        this.friends = friends;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="packageName", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private IAppsFriends friends;

    private String icon;

    private String name;

    public String getPackageName() {
        return packageName;
    }

    public void setPackageName(String packageName) {
        this.packageName = packageName;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping is incorrect:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "packageName")
private List<IAppEntity> apps;
```

That means that this OneToMany asscoaiation is the inverse side of a ManyToOne association declared on the field `packageName` of the `IAppEntity` entity. But the field `packageName` is declared as

```
@Id
private String packageName;
```

So it's not a ManyToOne at all.

Comment: thanks, I changed my code: swap OneToMany to ManyToOne and have correct results.